# With do Eloquent não está trazendo valor algum

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.2, estou tentando fazer um 'join' n para m com o 'With' do 'Eloquent' mas o mesmo não retorna valor algum, mesmo eles existindo no banco de dados.

Class Pessoa:

```
class Pessoa extends Authenticatable {
    const CREATED_AT = null;
    const UPDATED_AT = null;

    protected $table = 'pessoa';
    public $primaryKey = 'idPessoa';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function Perfis(){
        return $this->hasMany(Perfil::class, 'idPessoa', 'idPessoa');
    }

}

class Perfil extends Model {
    const CREATED_AT = null;
    const UPDATED_AT = null;

    protected $table = 'perfil';
    public $primaryKey = 'idPerfil';
    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

Requisição utilizada:

```
dd( Pessoa::with("Perfis")->has("Perfis")->first()->Perfis );
```

Resultado:

```
Collection {#341 ▼
   #items: []
}
```

Utilizei o 'DB::enableQueryLog();' para pegar os SQLs utilizados.

```
array:2 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select * from "pessoa" where exists (select * from "perfil" where "perfil"."idPessoa" = "pessoa"."idPessoa") limit 1"
        "bindings" => []
        "time" => 2.42
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select * from "perfil" where "perfil"."idPessoa" in (?)"
        "bindings" => array:1 [
             "0"=>"1"
        ]
        "time" => 1.33
    ]
]
```

Se eu executar o Segundo SQL eu recebo a lista de Perfis corretamente. Qual será o problema então?

Comment: Tem alguns pontos que não são padrões no Laravel uma são os nome do método da relação que está Perfis e no with você chamou Perfil já ta errado tem que ser o mesmo nome do método, e por padrão deve ser tudo minusculo ... se conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Corrigi, mas mesmo assim não funciona, e o mais engraçado que se eu tirar o with ele traz os valores. Mas fazendo deste modo cada vês que eu executar este método irá executar um SQL que acabaria com a performance.

Comment: Pedro seguinte o que você quer fazer com `with + has`, você poderia explicar melhor? Porque fazer um `Join` é outra forma? Quais resultados você precisa trazer? pode colocar todas as classes envolvidas

Comment: Estou tentando trazer todos os usuários que possuem perfis e seus respectivos perfis.

Comment: Coloque para mim as duas tabelas ou tabelas envolvidas na sua pergunta, N:M ta errado no Laravel por exemplo, então deixa eu ver o seu modelo de banco.